# multiple file reading issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having multiple text File with different name in single folder . i want to read All the File One by one -->> * Only Read Second File after finishing 1st . After Reading Successfully It should delete the file from Directory .I am Able to Read Single file . but when i am trying to read all files in one shot It is giving error .
how can i use thread for reading and delete the file.
All file having same format .

my sample code :

```
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("c:\codeo\testm.txt");
        string sLine="";
        ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

        while (sLine != null)
        {
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (sLine != null)
                arrText.Add(sLine);
        }
                    objReader.Close();

        foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
            Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

for del :

```
             private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
              if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
               {
                 File.Delete(fileLoc);
               }
             }
```

Comment: Its a nice habbit to accept peoples answers, before you ask new questions..

Comment: You are using this code in ASP.NET application ? Please fix tags, this is surely not asp-classic

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\codeo\\");
FileInfo[] fiArray = di.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo fi in fiArray)
{
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);
    string sLine = "";
    ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

    while (sLine != null)
    {
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
        if (sLine != null)
            arrText.Add(sLine);
    }
    objReader.Close();

    foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
        Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs some more clarification, such as what error you are receiving.  The way I would go about this is:

```
//Store all filenames within a List<string>
public void ReadFiles(List<string> filenames)
{
    string line = null;
    foreach(string file in filenames)
    {
        //The using will manage the closing and handle exceptions safely
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        if(File.Exists(file))
            File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

This code is untested, but I believe it should function correctly.  Does this help you at all?  I wrote this based on your need for the file to be deleted after being read - the button-based delete should be easy to implement.  If you need more clarification or help leave a comment.